# Editable ComboBox in wpf datagrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid, combobox

I have a problem with wpf datagrid combobox . I have the following code in which items are not getting populated in combobox please help me out if any one done this in wpf toolkit datagrid (NOT in Infragistics) and also let me know how to make that combobox column as editable one ?

```
  <DataGrid Name="dataGridResultsAdded" AutoGenerateColumns="False" FontWeight="Normal" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding UserResults,Mode=Default}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndexUserResults}" SelectionMode="Single" Margin="0,0,0,0" Height="178" GridLinesVisibility="None">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="RFC ID" Binding="{Binding RFCID}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="RFC Title" Binding="{Binding RFCTitle}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="RFC Revision" Binding="{Binding RFCRevision}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Trigger Association" Binding="{Binding TriggerAssociation}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="OrderStatus1" IsReadOnly="False">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Status, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBlock>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ComboBox IsEditable="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.OrderStatus,
                                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"                                           SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Status, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridComboBoxColumn IsReadOnly="False" Header="OrderStatus"  SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Status,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ItemsSource="{Binding OrderStatus, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Status" Binding="{Binding TriggerStatus}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

private List orderStatus = default(List);

```
    public List<string> OrderStatus
    {
        get
        {
            if (orderStatus == null)
            {
                orderStatus = new List<string>();
                orderStatus.Add("None");
                orderStatus.Add("New");
                orderStatus.Add("Processing");
                orderStatus.Add("Shipped");
            }
            return orderStatus;
        }
        set
        {
            orderStatus = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("OrderStatus");
        }
    }
```

`
public DataTable dtUserResults = default(DataTable);

```
    public DataTable UserResults
    {
        get
        {
            return dtUserResults;
        }
        set
        {
            dtUserResults = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("UserResults");
        }
    }
```

`View Model Code Below

```
    public void AddExecute()
    {
        InfoHandler.LogInfo("Entering AddExecute");
        try
        {
            DataTable dtUserRes = new DataTable();
            DataColumn dColumn = default(DataColumn);
            DataRow dRow = default(DataRow);

            DataRow dRowSelected = dtSearchResults.NewRow();
            dRowSelected = dtSearchResults.Rows[intSelectedIndexSearchRes];

            if (dtSearchResults.Rows.Count > 0 && IsRFCAlreadyAdded(dRowSelected))
            {
                dColumn = new DataColumn("RFCID", Type.GetType("System.String"));   
                dtUserRes.Columns.Add(dColumn);

                dColumn = new DataColumn("RFCTitle", Type.GetType("System.String"));
                dtUserRes.Columns.Add(dColumn);

                dColumn = new DataColumn("RFCRevision", Type.GetType("System.String"));
                dtUserRes.Columns.Add(dColumn);

                dColumn = new DataColumn("TriggerAssociation", Type.GetType("System.String"));
                dtUserRes.Columns.Add(dColumn);

                dColumn = new DataColumn("TriggerStatus", Type.GetType("System.String"));
                dtUserRes.Columns.Add(dColumn);

                //setting RFCID as primary key for the datatable UserResults
                dtUserRes.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dtUserRes.Columns[0] };

                dRow = dtUserRes.NewRow();
                dRow["RFCID"] = dRowSelected["RFCID"];
                dRow["RFCTitle"] = dRowSelected["RFCTitle"];
                dRow["RFCRevision"] = dRowSelected["RFCRevision"];
                dRow["TriggerAssociation"] = "Manual";
                dRow["TriggerStatus"] = "N";
                dtUserRes.Rows.Add(dRow);

                if (UserResults == null)
                {
                    UserResults = new DataTable();
                }
                UserResults.Merge(dtUserRes, true);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception objEx)
        {
            ErrorHandler.ShowErrorMessage(strErrorCaption, "Error occured while Adding RFC from Search results to Execution List", objEx.Message);
        }
        InfoHandler.LogInfo("Exiting AddExecute");
    }
```

`

Thanks
NallsKarthi

Comment: Could you add some code of your viewmodel, such as : what is the ItemsSource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is normal, you are not asking the `ComboBox` to be populated by many values.

As long as I understand correctly your problem, you have

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=OrderStatus, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Status, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

What is the type of the object `OrderStatus` ?
And moreover, where is situated OrderStatus?

I'd say as a suggestion:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.OrderStatus,
  RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" 
  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Status, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

(if you are in a Window, change the AncestorType to Window)

To be sure, I'd need more code here, especially: the declaration of  your ItemsSource, and the declaration of the `OrderStatus`

Comment: OrderStatus is List<string> is that correct one? It is in Viewmodel.

Comment: Okay, I got it. The problem here is that you have to know that when you apply a `Binding` in a `DataGrid`'s column, the actual `DataContext` is the DataGrid's `ItemSource`. So, it won't find your list `OrderStatus`, because it is located in your ViewModel. To access it, use the suggestion I gave you: adding a `RelativeSource`, which will look into the `DataGrid`'s parent `DataContext`, and appropriately find the correct list :)

Comment: @damascus: Still its not working i have changed whatever you have mentioned above :( I have used **Relative Source** also but still list not getting populated . is that right way am using list<string> or any other type i should use?

Comment: Where exactly is located your `DataGrid` ? in a `UserControl` or `Window` ?

Comment: Moreover, can you check what's displayed on Visual Studio's Output Window? It should give you a binding error if it doesn't find the list

Comment: No its not throwing any error also and the **get { } ** getter is not even getting called in the OrderStatus Property

Comment: @damascus: its working :) fine thanks :) problem is i did **Datagrid** as _non editable_ set the property is IsReadonly="True" so now i changed to **false** its working cool thanks :)